# Count number data rows entered into a 2 dimensional array

Tags: arrays, vb.net

Forgive me is there is another question like this, but I could not find it!!

Here is my problem, and I am sure it is a stupid one. I have a 2 dimensional array called supplyItems(49,4).

What I can't seem to find anything on is if I only enter 2 rows of data into the array. For example a user enters data and it is inserted into supplyItems(0, 0), supplyItems(0, 1), etc. to supplyItems(0, 4) and then a second line supplyItems(1, 0), supplyItems(1, 1), etc. to supplyItems(1, 4).

The exact number of lines will not be know. I need to count the number of entries (Rows) that have been entered by the user.

I have tried all of the following to no avail;

```
supplyItems.Length
supplyItems.Length(0)
supplyItems.GetLength
supplyItems.GetLength(0)
supplyItems.GetUpperBound
supplyItems.GetUpperBound(0)
```

None of these will give the row count. How in the world do i get the row count?? I do not need to count the total number of elements, or the total number of rows, just the number of rows of data that have been inserted.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: If its a fixed size array none of that stuff will help you. A fixed size array is usually not the best approach for this type of activity.

Comment: You would be better to make it a list of a structure or class

Comment: what is the type of the array and how do you populate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with `supplyItems.GetLength(0)` you are obtaining basically the **TOTAL** number of rows of the array, and with `supplyItems.GetLength(1)` you are obtaining the **TOTAL** number of columns of the array.
Lets say you have more than one row(49) and you only entered the input of the first two, if you don't count them in a certain way with a counter

```
int rowCouter = 0;
```

and increasing the `rowCounter ++;` as you finished the data entered in one row and going to the other, then you are not able to know how many rows you entered, unless you iterate over your array identifying the filled rows and counting them

Comment: How do I iterate over the array to find the filled rows? That is what I am after.

Comment: You would need to initialize the array with values that would not normally be used. like -1, or double.null or somesuch. It depends on your data

Comment: if the array is an array of int, then you should be seeing 0 values on the entire row, if its is a reference type like string[,] then all the values are null, or you can do the @Trevor advice, if it is an array of int[,], try to initialize all values with a default -1. But that introduce a cost doing that because you need to iterate through the entire array assigning the corresponding value(-1) on this case

Comment: But, If I might be so bold, why are you using an array? That is an old school method. There are MUCH better ways to do it in vb.net.

Comment: at least with a linear array you can do it on this way more easily, but I am not aware of another method for a dimensional one Enumerable.Repeat(-1, 10).ToArray()

Comment: I re coded to add a global variable to track number of entries. Thanks Zinov